# pigpio: PWM range for quadcopter ESC(electronic speed controller) command

Tags: pwm, c++, pigpio

Good day,
I am currently working on a quadcopter project and am currently using the pigpio library for the PWM used to command the ESC's of the quadcopter motors.

> Will increasing the range of the values used let say (0-40000) from (0-255), will there be a noticable improvement with the fineness or precision of the response of the motors?

I am currently using the default range of 0-255 and a frequency of 400Hz.

int gpioSetPWMrange(unsigned user_gpio, unsigned range);
from: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetPWMrange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, changing the range will make no difference to the underlying number of steps between off and fully on.

The following table shows the permitted PWM frequencies at each sample rate.

```
                      Hertz

       1: 40000 20000 10000 8000 5000 4000 2500 2000 1600
           1250  1000   800  500  400  250  200  100   50

       2: 20000 10000  5000 4000 2500 2000 1250 1000  800
            625   500   400  250  200  125  100   50   25

       4: 10000  5000  2500 2000 1250 1000  625  500  400
            313   250   200  125  100   63   50   25   13
sample
 rate
 (us)  5:  8000  4000  2000 1600 1000  800  500  400  320
            250   200   160  100   80   50   40   20   10

       8:  5000  2500  1250 1000  625  500  313  250  200
            156   125   100   63   50   31   25   13    6

      10:  4000  2000  1000  800  500  400  250  200  160
            125   100    80   50   40   25   20   10    5
```

So for a sample rate of 5 µs the permitted frequencies are
8000, 4000, 2000, 1600, 1000, 800, 500, 400, 320, 250, 200,
160, 100, 80, 50, 40, 20, and 10 Hz.

---

The number of steps between off and fully on depends on both
the sampling rate and the frequency and is given by the following
formula

steps = 1000000 / (sample rate * frequency)

For example a sample rate of 5 µs and frequency 1600 Hz has

1000000 / (5 * 1600) = 125 steps

For a sample rate of 5 µs and frequency of 400 Hz

1000000 / (5 * 400) = 500 steps

---

You can use any range which is convenient for your application, perhaps 0-100 if percents make sense, 0-360 if it is an angle.

However, whatever range (0-X) you use, behind the scenes it will automatically be scaled to (0-steps).

Comment: Thank you so much, I was very close to wasting my time recalculating pid constants because of this due to the rescaling :)